# NSNumber with commas

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

Maybe this is a silly answer but I'm pretty new on ios.. I have to show a number in an specific way in my app. Currently, I have numbers that I receive from a service in an NSString. But, e.g. if I have a number: 123456789, i need to show it in a label as 123.456.789 .. anyone knows if there is some way to do that?

Edit: add ios and iphone tags

Comment: Have you searched the site at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[attributesDict objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize]];
NSLog(@"System free space: %@", formattedOutput);
```

If your number comes in as a string first, you'll need to make a number out of it first which you can do using `NSString`'s `intValue` method:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/intValue

Comment: Sure! Though Sulthan is right; a bit more searching would probably have turned up similar info. :)

Comment: In deed, I was trying some things with nsnumberformatter, but i didn't understand very well how that works. I did some research, but maybe because i'm newbie i couldnt find the solution. Anyway, I have been punished with 2 points here :P.. my english is so poor, I'm so soory

Comment: solution: NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
            [formatter setAllowsFloats:NO];
            [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
            [formatter setGroupingSize:3];
        
            thePrice = [formatter stringFromNumber:_price];
            [formatter release];

Comment: Your English is good enough for us to understand what you want, so don't worry about that. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@", myNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[numFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_US"]];
[numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[numFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[numFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
NSString * newString =  [numFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:43423423423242]];
```